# Indexing & applying func to pandas DataFrame with a DateOffset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, time-series

Take the following DataFrame of normally distributed terms with a small drift:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(60,3) / 100 + 0.005, 
                  index=pd.date_range(end='2017-06-30', periods=60, freq='M'))
```

and define a function `rollup` that will be applied to the columns:

```
def rollup(r):
    return r.add(1.).prod() -1.
```

For example, calling on the entire `df` gives me:

```
print(rollup(df))
0    0.17411
1    0.35658
2    0.24944
dtype: float64
```

But what I'd like to do is take a date offset from the final date in the index of `df`, and apply `rollup` to that sub-frame.  I'm getting to this correctly, as below, but wondering if there is an alternative method using a few less lines.

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import DateOffset
end = df.index[-1]

start = end - DateOffset(years=2)    
print(df[start:end].apply(rollup))
0    0.07905
1    0.18037
2    0.09656
dtype: float64

# example 2
start = end - DateOffset(months=6)    
print(df[start:end].apply(rollup))
0    0.01656
1    0.06585
2    0.01463
dtype: float64
```

Can this final bit of code be condensed?  Is there another method within [Time Series / Date functionality](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#) that doesn't require me to specify `end`, apply a `DateOffset`, and then index `df` between the two?

If this is the most straightforward method requiring the least code, that to me is an answer in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, I'd say your code is pretty concise.  I'll make this observation and suggestion:

Your index was created with a frequency of `'M'` and that carries over to each individual `Timestamp`.  What that means is that those objects now know how to process addition and subtraction of integers.  What `pandas` does is assumes the integer takes on the offset represented by the frequency.

**Example**

```
df.index[-1]

Timestamp('2017-06-30 00:00:00', freq='M')
```

And

```
df.index[-1] - 2

Timestamp('2017-04-30 00:00:00', freq='M')
```

We can use this to accomplish your goals with

```
rollup(df[df.index[-1] - 2:])  # last 2 months
```

And

```
rollup(df[df.index[-1] - 24:])  # last 2 years
```

---

Extra Credit

This math also works on the entire index.

```
df.index + 2
```

Adds two months to each index value.

Comment: Thanks.  I actually chose to use specific [`DateOffset`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) objects rather than the generic `DateOffset`.  And will probably keep code as-is because I'm working with different frequencies at times.

Comment: Fair enough... as I said, your code looked good to begin with :-)